# Оценки по предметам

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Здравствуйте. Прошу помочь в создании бд. Суть такая: будет небольшой скрипт, где можно узнать оценки по предметам (простенький, он использоваться не будет, такое задание:))
У каждого  свой номер зачетки, при вводе оценок из выпадающего меню (select) выбирается нужная студента зачетка и вводится цифра оценки. Но у каждого студента множество оценок (т.е. на один номер зачетки несколько оценок). Примерно представил это так (MS SQL).

Таблица студенты:

```
create table students
(
stud_id bigint primary key,
stud_name char(200),
stud_fam char(254)
);
```

Таблица с оценками

```
CREATE TABLE ocenki
(
stud_id bigint foreign key references students(stud_id),
predmet char(254),
ocenka integer check (ocenka in (0,1,2,3,4,5)) default(0)
);
```

Как код будет выглядеть в MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

В общем и целом SQL - одинаковый у всех субд, в данном случае запрос корректен и для Mysql( естественно в начале необходимо выбрать БД :) )

Мне не понятно другое...

**Bigint** - большое целое число. Диапазон со знаком от -9223372036854775808 до 9223372036854775807, неужели студентов будет **НАСТОЛЬКО** много? :D

Достаточно просто int

Comment: Спасибо:) Но он ведь позволит повторяться значению STUD_ID в таблице с оценками?
Т.е.
------
Stud_id = 1
Predmet = matan
ocenka = 5
------
Stud_id = 1
Predmet = fizika
ocenka = 4
И тд.
В конце должно получиться: http://image.kz/v3d8ca13ff473ce5dd95d096580f34cc1 (скрин)

Comment: Сделайте отдельный int primary key для таблицы студентов, а stud_id просто занесите в index.

И вообще, насколько я понял задачу - в таблице students надо добавить поле для номера зачетки( естественно uniqe key ), и связывать таблицу оценок нужно именно с номером зачетки а не с id студента.

PS:не тратьте свои очки уважения, достаточно просто проголосовать за.

Comment: Ну) предполагается что Stud_id и будет номером зачетки:) Он не повторяется и идеально подходит:) в поиске будут вбивать именно его. Я ввожу 081028 и он выводит оценки
select predmet, ocenka
from ocenki
where stud_id='$value'
Извиняюсь еси по нубски))Сам от программирования далек) как понял из книжек, так и пишу)

Comment: Студент и зачетка разные сущности....

У вас в таблице каша получается... ID **студента** - это на самом деле ID **зачетки**, так делать неправильно( хотя такую кашу творят многие даже бывалые спецы ), конечно с точкизрения количества хранимых данных ваше решение верно,вообщем то это уже споры "о высоком", можете сделать так как вы и хотели, но переименуйте как-то stud_id чтобы было понятно что это номер зачетки а не id студента.

И bigint не к чему (это я надеюсь вы уже поняли :))

Comment: да) насчёт бигинта спасибо))

Answer (score 0):

Я рекомендовал бы для предметов завести отдельную таблицу, а в Оценках ставить id_предмет. Кроме того, за один и тот же предмет ставят несколько оценок в различные семестры. Так чта-а-а еще и номер семестра потребуется. id_студент + семестр + id_предмет -совместно-уникальные поля.